# How to use undo/redo in CKEditor without toolbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm using [CKEditor 4.2.2](http://ckeditor.com/) without default toolbar, because I want to use my own toolbar.

CKEditor has [UndoManager](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.UndoManager), which has 4 function which I need: `undo()`, `redo()`, `undoable()`, `redoable()`.

In my html I have:

```
<textarea id='doc'>
```

In javascript:

```
$('#' + textareaId).ckeditor();
m_Editor = CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId];
```

I have tried to to use:

- `m_Editor.undo` - `undefined`
- `m_Editor.plugins.undo`

Here is a CKEditor instance for current textarea in console:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CKEditor registers [commands](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.command) which can be executed with [`CKEDITOR.editor.execCommand`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-execCommand). I think that `m_Editor.execCommand( 'undo' )` should do the trick for you.

Bonus: Inspect `m_Editor.commands` to know what commands are under the hood.

Comment: When I inspecting `m_Editor` throw console, `m_Editor.commands` is `Object` with a lot of commands, but when I try to inspect `m_Editor.commands`, it is undefined.

Comment: It's a matter of when you inspect those objects. Do it manually once the page is loaded via `CKEDITOR.instances.m_Editor.commands`. Should be fine.

Comment: @oleq You are awesome. Thanks for this. Must have saved hours for sure.. Cheers!!!!